# Помогите устранить ошибку

Tags: c#

Вчера еще все работало, сегодня пришел домой и один из элементов игры перестал отвечать и стало выдавать эту ошибку:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: String
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: String

Source Error:

```
Line 38:         string gid = "";
Line 39: 
Line 40:         byte room = Byte.Parse(postedValues["room"]);
Line 41:         if(room>5 || room<0)
Line 42:         {
```

Comment: а это точно javascript? больше похоже на C#

Comment: угу, я перепутал ибо уже задолбался ломать голову над ошибкой этой

Comment: Вы действительно считаете, что по приведенному коду можно сказать в чем дело?

Comment: могу дать ссылку на детальное описание ошибки, если тут конечно можно ссылки давать

Comment: очевидно что тут `postedValues["room"]` null. проверяйте почему

Comment: @АлексейШиманский: Думаю, ТС излишне сильно доверяет пришедшим от клиента данным.

Comment: хм, спасибо, пойду проверять